# Why does angular binding breaks between directives when transcluded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following scenario

I combined a page with a controller and several directives, one with transclude switch on (which seems to cause the problem).

When I click on "changeMe()" the value of the scope change to `erez`.

When I click on "close" we assign `null` to the property on the scope within the directive. I verified the same scenario with values other than null...

When I click on "changeMe()" again... nothing happens!! Why is that? How do I fix it?

The HTML template

```
<div my-layout="">
  <button ng-click="changeName()">Change me!</button>
  <div>
     {{name}} - This is my name directive
     <div my-name name="name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript code

```
angular.module('guy', []);

angular.module('guy').controller('GuyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'guy';

  $scope.changeName = function(){
    $scope.name = 'erez';
  }
});


angular.module('guy').directive('myName',function ($log) {
        return {
            template: '<div> my name is: {{name}} <button ng-click="close()">Close</button></div>',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                name : '=name'
            },
            link: function postLink($scope, element) {
              $scope.close = function(){
                $scope.name = null;
              }
            }
        }
    }
);


angular.module('guy').directive('myLayout',function ($log) {
        return {
            template: '<div>This is the grand layout<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude:true, 


            link: function postLink($scope, element) {
                 $log.info('linking layout');
            }
        }
    }
);
```

You can use [this plunkr to run it](http://plnkr.co/edit/zOGk5XTvH62yVV3NJjOo?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a victim of prototypical scope inheritance. In short: never use 1st level (i.e. `$scope.xxx`) properties for 2-way binding. Rather, use a wrapper object (`data` or `model` are convenient names) as: `$scope.data = { name: 'guy' }`.

What happens is that, with prototypical scope inheritance, the `myLayout` directive creates a NEW scope under the controller's scope. So, whenever it reads from a 1st level property that doesn't exist, i.e. `$scope.name`, it reads from the parent. When it writes, it writes to itself. And further reads access itself too. *The changes to 1st level inherited properties are never propagated to the prototypical parent!*

Checkout a forked [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/14m8tYRGsIuHdPyQZ5lh?p=preview) with this principle; and make sure you understand Javascript's prototypical inheritance, it is applied on Angular's scopes.